# Blank symbol on output tape

Tags: turing-machines

A unary Turing Machine X has input alphabet Σ and tape alphabet Γ. We represent the blank symbol belonging to the tape alphabet as _ . Given as input 11111 X writes 1_1_11_1 as output.

Is the blank symbol discarded when considering the output, ie. is the input equivalent to the output in this case (regardless of how many blanks and where they are placed (1_11_11 = 1111_1 = ... = 11111)) or are they differnt?

Comment: $1\_11\_11$, $1111\_1$ and $11111$ are different words over the alphabet $\{1,\_\}$.

Comment: @plop The blank symbol is not part of the input alphabet, {1} (unary in this case). Blank symbol is only part of tape alphabet.

Comment: Why are you telling that information? Is it related to what I said?

Comment: @plop This is my point of confusion. Is the "output alphabet" equivalent to the tape alphabet or to the input alphabet? Do we get rid of all the blanks before reading out output or do we take them into consideration and the output includes the blanks and their placement?

Comment: @plop for example, if we had a binary Turing Machine the input alphabet would be {0,1} but the tape alphabet would include special blank symbol marking the rest of the tape where there is no input written. After edits have been made these blanks can find their way between the 1's and 0's. my question is when looking at the tape after computation has ended what do we do about these interspersed blanks? do we just ignore them?

Comment: Words with different characters in some position are different. Whether one interpret some different words are equivalent according to some equivalence relation is up to whoever it using the Turing machine. The machine (the concept not a particular instance) doesn't have any notion of identification of words. The point of saying that the input is a word in the alphabet that excludes the blank character is just a way of saying that the input is a finite part of the (potentially) infinite tape.

Comment: It is not part of the Turing machine what you do with what is written in the tape, how you interpret it.

Comment: Some people allow the blank to be part of the input alphabet, but require that only finitely many cells of the infinite tape are set to non-blank characters.

Comment: @plop -- think i understand. It is up to me whether  1_11_1 is the same as 11_1_1. word equivalence isn't part of TM definition. but at a most granular level these can be considered different words to a user of the TM.

Comment: @plop my question was basically can 1_1_1 vs 111 be considered different words-- I didn't know if the blank symbol counted as an actual difference. Thanks.